# OrientDB How to check the relationship between 2 node

Tags: orientdb

I have some vertices of class '`Product`' which can be '`viewed`', or '`ordered`' by class '`User`'..
My problem is that I want to write SQL query or MATCH command to get all Product which is '`viewed`' by specific user, but it hasn't been ordered by any user..

How to check the relationship '`ordered`' doesn't exist between '`Product`' and '`User`' in MATCH command?

Eg:

> ProductA <-viewed- UserA  
>  ProductB <-viewed- UserA
>  ProductC
>   <-viewed- UserA
>  ProductD <-viewed- UserA
>  ProductA <-ordered-
>   UserA 
>  ProductD <-viewed- UserB
>  ProductD <-ordered-
>   UserB

Input: `User A`
Output: `ProductB, ProductC`

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
MATCH {CLASS:Product, AS:pdt, WHERE: (in().size() == 1 and inE().@class = "viewed" and in().name contains "UserA")} RETURN pdt.name
```

this is the output:

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
MATCH {CLASS:Product, AS:pdt, WHERE: (in("viewed").name contains 'UserA' and in("ordered").size()=0)} RETURN pdt.name
```

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: Thank you. But if I add the relationship '`viewed`' between UserB and ProductC, your query will wrong. It should be return both ProductB and ProductC.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this query

```
select from Product where in("viewed").@rid contains userRid and in("ordered").size()=0
```

Hope it helps.